# Is Mysqldatasource thread safe

Tags: java, jdbc, thread-safety, datasource

Does it implement a connection pool? 
I believe PostgreSQL JDBC driver is thread safe but I am not sure on MYSQL.

I am making a static object for handling DB connections like this
    package com.amzi.DataAccess;

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

public class DBUtil {
    private static MysqlDataSource dataSource = null;

    public static MysqlDataSource getDataSource() {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
            dataSource.setUser("root");
            dataSource.setPassword(""); // Put your password here
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_device_table");
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And in another class I create a connection to see if a record exists.
Once I am done with the connection, I close it.

```
public boolean ValidateLogin(User user) {
    boolean status = false;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DBUtil.getDataSource().getConnection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from users where user_name=? and password=?");
        ps.setString(1, user.getUsername());
        ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        status = rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: In most cases (unless you're using older versions of Tomcat) you should use your application server's configuration for setting up DataSources. This is always accompanied with connection pool configuration.

Comment: @SteveC is a connection pool necessary? Say I am running 3 different laptops all on localhost but they are all connected to the same remote db? would a pool be needed in this case?

Comment: If you ever need to scale up so that you can have 10s, 100s or 1000s of users then using a connection pool will help a lot.

Comment: @SteveC how can I configure this? could i do it on the client side or tomcat?

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: what's the difference if i change the context.xml in the server versus adding my own context.xml in my solution?

Comment: If you put the configuration in the server then you can have different configs for each environment (dev, QA and production). You connection pool size might be 100 in production, 40-50 for QA and 10-20 for development. You want to avoid building different WARs for each environment if you can.

Comment: ok i get that so for resource type, would it be <Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"/> or would i make it the implementation? <Resource type="../MySQLDataResource"/>

Comment: i am assuming it would be the interface that i'd set the type as, so that even if my DataResource is not MySQL (say Oracle), it would still be able to adapt and work. Am I correct to assume this?

Comment: Just use javax.sql.DataSource everywhere. Be sure to always get new connections using [Try with Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so that you don't have to worry about forgetting those `finally` blocks and their own exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

The `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` is a basic data source. That is, it creates connections, but doesn't provide a connection pool.

Its connection creation uses the basic MySQL `java.sql.Driver` implementation, just like using `DriverManager.getConnection` would. In other words, it is as thread-safe as the driver itself is.

In general, using a connection pool however is advisable. Either use the functionality provided by your application / server (or Tomcat), or use a dedicated connection pool library (eg HikariCP, DBCP, etc).

Comment: What I mean is DataSource is an interface...MysqlDataSource is an implementation of DataSource. When I create an object of type MysqlDataSource (say called ds), when I invoke the ds.getConnection(), does it get a connection from the connection pool? And when I call ds.close(), does it close the connection and release it back to the pool?

Comment: @YusufJama Please read my answer carefully, I explicitly address that: _"it creates connections, but doesn't provide a connection pool"_. So no, it doesn't use a connection pool. Also a data source has no `close()` method, but assuming you meant connection, then no: if directly obtained from `MysqlDataSource`, then calling close will close the physical connection.